# Median of 3 taking more time than usual quicksort in java

Tags: java, sorting, quicksort, median, median-of-medians

I have a quicksort code in java which I want to improve. The improved code should take less time than the quicksort code. However when using my improved code which implement median of 3 partitioning, it takes 400 miliseconds more. Can anybody help me solve this out? if possible, can you suggest me other possible ways to improve my code. I have from 10,000 to 10 million integers to sort.

Quicksort

```
public void quickSort(int arr[], int begin, int end) {
    if (begin < end) {
        int partitionIndex = partition(arr, begin, end);

        quickSort(arr, begin, partitionIndex-1);
        quickSort(arr, partitionIndex+1, end);
    }


}

private int partition(int arr[], int begin, int end) {
    int pivot = arr[end];
    int i = (begin-1);

    for (int j = begin; j < end; j++) {
        if (arr[j] <= pivot) {
            i++;

            int swapTemp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = swapTemp;
        }
    }

    int swapTemp = arr[i+1];
    arr[i+1] = arr[end];
    arr[end] = swapTemp;

    return i+1;
}

}
```

Improved code

```
package sorting;


public class improvement {

Clock c = new Clock();

  public void quickSort(int[] intArray) {

    recQuickSort(intArray, 0, intArray.length - 1);

  }

  public static void recQuickSort(int[] intArray, int left, int right) {
    int size = right - left + 1;
    if (size <= 3)
      manualSort(intArray, left, right);
    else {
      double median = medianOf3(intArray, left, right);
      int partition = partitionIt(intArray, left, right, median);
      recQuickSort(intArray, left, partition - 1);
      recQuickSort(intArray, partition + 1, right);
    }
  }

  public static int medianOf3(int[] intArray, int left, int right) {
  int center = (left + right) / 2;

    if (intArray[left] > intArray[center])
      swap(intArray, left, center);

    if (intArray[left] > intArray[right])
     swap(intArray, left, right);

   if (intArray[center] > intArray[right])
     swap(intArray, center, right);

   swap(intArray, center, right - 1);
   return intArray[right - 1];
  }

  public static void swap(int[] intArray, int dex1, int dex2) {
    int temp = intArray[dex1];
    intArray[dex1] = intArray[dex2];
    intArray[dex2] = temp;
 }

  public static int partitionIt(int[] intArray, int left, int right, double 
  pivot) {
    int leftPtr = left;
    int rightPtr = right - 1;

     while (true) {
       while (intArray[++leftPtr] < pivot) 
       ;
       while (intArray[--rightPtr] > pivot)
       ;
       if (leftPtr >= rightPtr)
         break;
       else
       swap(intArray, leftPtr, rightPtr);
    }
    swap(intArray, leftPtr, right - 1);
    return leftPtr;
 }

 public static void manualSort(int[] intArray, int left, int right) {
    int size = right - left + 1;
    if (size <= 1)
     return;
   if (size == 2) {
  if (intArray[left] > intArray[right])
    swap(intArray, left, right);
  return;
} else {
  if (intArray[left] > intArray[right - 1])
    swap(intArray, left, right - 1);
  if (intArray[left] > intArray[right])
    swap(intArray, left, right);
  if (intArray[right - 1] > intArray[right])
    swap(intArray, right - 1, right);
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked around the internet? This is pretty common. My first search using `median 3 partitioning java` resulted in a full page of different variations.

Comment: post your in [code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: @Mr00Anderson Am I on the right track if I am using median 3 partitioning?

Comment: The code is a variation of [Lomuto partition scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Lomuto_partition_scheme). It would be faster to use a variation of [Hoare partition scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme). Note after partition, the recursive call uses pivot and pivot+1, instead of pivot-1 and pivot+1. The Hoare scheme ends up with the pivot or an element equal to the pivot at either the end of the left partition or at the start of the right partition.

Comment: I just noticed double medium = medianof3(...), that should be int medium = medianof3(...). With the double, it's getting converted from int to double on the medianof3 call and converted back to int on the partitionIt call. You could include the logic for mediumof3 inside of partitionIt to reduce the call overhead.